# Java Formatter, float values, exception on exceeding maximum width

Tags: java, exception, floating-point, formatter

I want to use the java.util.Formatter class for formatting fixed-length records. The record includes Integer and Double fields.

For any Integer and Double for which the corresponding string representation fits into the specified width (eg "12.345" 'fits' into "%3.3d"), that's no problem, I can have the value padded to '012.345'. However, if my Double would **exceed** the specified width, like '1234.567', the '%3.3d' conversion format would result in '1234.567', which would screw up the fixed-length record definition.

I would like to get an Exception on such cases, so my program can do appropriate error handling. Eg I'd like to see something like:

```
String r = null;
try {
    r = String.format("%3.3d", new Double(1234.567));
} catch (SomeFormatException e) {
    // do error handling
}
```

Is there any conversion flag that I can use to achieve this?

Comment: maybe IllegalFormatPrecisionException

Comment: yes, but 9.3, 8.3, 7.3, 6.3 do not throw

Comment: @dacwe, an IllegalFormatPrecsionException is thrown for an invalid format specification, NOT by data that doesn't fit. In the above example, "r" would be set to "1234.567", without any exceptions, even though the integer part is larger than the width I specified.